# Can any AWS capture data that sent via GPS tracker using a tcp socket connection?

Tags: sockets, amazon-web-services, gps

I wonder if there is any service in **Amazon Web Services** that i can use to catch the **GPS** data that send from my GPS tracker to a specific **host:port** or **domain:port** ?
My device is not a MQTT client so i can't use **AWS IOT**

Is **EC2** the only choice ?

I want to integrate those GPS information in my web app ,right now it's in heroku hosting  but i plan to transfer it to AWS  if i solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with the interfaces that your GPS trackers use. However, provided that you open the IP / Port in your security group so that your GPS tracker can connect to your own software, it will work.

[EDIT after question]

There are many ways (and services) in Amazon to capture data. **The real answer depends on how your GPS tracker is connecting to an endpoint, how it is sending data and what interface it expects.**

If your tracker supports using a REST style interface, you could use API Gateway with Lambda to process your tracker data and store in DynamoDB, S3, etc. Kinesis Firehose might be another service that could work.

Comment: ec2 instances is the only choice  to catch the tcp socket data ?

Comment: the device is a micro-controller the only thing that  it accept is domain:port or ip:port  ,  can you guide me with  any Amazon web service that can listen to a specific port (or tcp socket) and wait for incoming data ?

Comment: The answer is in the details. You will have to do your own research for this one.

Comment: @ZakariaMasaoudi there is currently no managed service from AWS that will listen on a raw socket for arbitrary data streams.

Comment: Thank you John Hanley , Michael - sqlbot  for the informations